# How to find the difference between 2 list models

Tags: c#, list, linq

Faced with problem of comparing 2 list of models.

```
public class Relations
    {
        [key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CounterpartyId { get; set; }
        public int CounterpartyTypeId { get; set; }
        public int DebTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

I have method witch take list of this models from frontend and list that I take from the database. when came model from frontend it has not id and I do not add id to this model.
for example:

```
            var models = new List<Relations>()
            {
                new Relations
                {
                    CounterpartyId = 1,
                    CounterpartyTypeId = 1,
                    DebTypeId = 1
                },
                new Relations
                {
                    CounterpartyId = 1,
                    CounterpartyTypeId = 2,
                    DebTypeId = 1001
                }
            };

            var entity = new List<Relations>()
            {
                new Relations
                {
                    CounterpartyId = 1,
                    CounterpartyTypeId = 1,
                    DebTypeId = 1
                },
                
            };
```

How compared this 2 list of models??? i need insert model which has (CounterpartyId = 1, CounterpartyTypeId = 2, DebTypeId = 1001)

In order to avoid duplicates in db, I try

```
IEnumerable<Relations> toInsert = models.Except<Relations>(entity);
```

and try

```
var test=(from m in models select m).Except(entity).ToList();
```

but they are the same and cannot find data that is not in the database

Comment: You could add a custom comparer; see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1?view=netframework-4.8). You can use that to determine which fields in your class constitute a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter Smith suggested on comment section you can create your [`Comparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1):

```
sealed class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Relations>
{
    public bool Equals(Relations x, Relations y)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return y == null;
        else if (y == null)
            return false;
        else
            return x.CounterpartyId == y.CounterpartyId  && x.CounterpartyTypeId == y.CounterpartyTypeId && x.DebTypeId == y.DebTypeId ;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Relations obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And use `Except()` overload as follows:

```
IEnumerable<Relations> toInsert = models.Except<Relations>(entity, new MyComparer());
```